# jQuery if input is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    $("#search_input").autocomplete({
    source: results,
    select: function(e, i) {
  $('#searchresultdata').text(i.item.value);
 }
    }).on("keyup change",function() {
    var search_input = $(this).val();
    if (search_input.length > 0 && search_input != "Begin typing to search...") {
        $('#searchresultdata').text("RAWR");
    }
    $('#searchresultdata').text(search_input);
}
);
```

Thats my code for a search box (search_input).  Basically, I just want it so that if the box is empty or contains "Begin typing to search..." to display RAWR, if not, show what was typed into the search_input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `.text(search_input);` regardless of whether or not your condition matches.

You need to put this into an `else` statement:

```
if (search_input.length > 0 && search_input != "Begin typing to search...") {
        $('#searchresultdata').text("RAWR");
    }
    else
    {
        $('#searchresultdata').text(search_input);
    }
```

Comment: *sigh* what a muppet!  Thanks.